# How to export orders by date via SQL?

Tags: magento2, database, orders, sales-order, sql

I'm using a Magento 2.3 instance, how could I export my orders in a CSV file by date range via SQL?

I want to have the **shippingId**, **orderId** and **paymentId** included in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the below query and you can generate CSV from a database.

```
SELECT  O.entity_id AS "Order ID",
    P.entity_id AS "Payment ID",
        S.entity_id AS "Shipment ID"
FROM sales_order O
     LEFT JOIN sales_order_payment P ON (O.entity_id = P.parent_id)
     LEFT JOIN sales_shipment S ON (O.entity_id = S.entity_id)
     WHERE O.created_at between '2019-12-01' and '2020-11-11'
ORDER BY O.created_at
```